# Start fragment from onCreate() when Back Pressed

Tags: java, android, fragment, oncreate, onbackpressed

I have two fragments.
There is some code in the onCreate() of fragment1.
When I'm in fragment2 and press back, it goes to fragment1 and start from onCreateView(). But I need the code that is in the onCreate() to run.

In Activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.host_fragment, new Fragment1()).commit();
```

In fragment1 I have button that navigate to fragment2:

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("").
                        replace(R.id.host_fragment,Fragment2).commit();
```

And I don't have any code for onBackPressed() in activity.

The activity that has fragments, **It's not** MainActivity.**java**

Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue using only onCreateView() instead of onCreate?

Comment: Why is your code in `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateView()` if you want it to run every time your view is created?

Comment: I put my  non graphical initializations in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need not do that, it is already okay. When you put fragment1 into backstack and then press back, `onCreateView()` of fragment1 is called only if that previously instantiated fragment1 instance is in memory. If not in memory, all the fragment lifecycle callbacks are called accordingly, including `onCreate()`.

So, if you make your non graphical initializations in `onCreate()`, they are already initialized, when you press back; or at least be initialized if it is created as new. All these will be managed by fragment manager.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you put your code inside `OnCreate()`?
if no then put your code inside `OnCreateView()‍‍‍‍‍‍‍` because `OnCreateView()` is called right after `OnCreate()`. so if you want to call that code on fragment creation it's guaranteed that your code is called.
also if you look at fragment lifecycle you can see that if a fragment is returned from backstack, its `OnCreateView()` method will be called. so when you come back from your second fragment, your code will run.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workflow is move your code which need to execute every time from `onCreate()` method to `onResume()`.

`onResume()` calls every time when user focus on the screen. Or from background to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.

First I thought my problem was just because of `onCreate()`, but after I put my code inside the `onCreateView()`, my problem was still remains.

So, I decided to restart the fragment when Back Pressed. So I came up with this solution:

In the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.host_fragment, new Fragment1()).commit();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Is that efficient?